# ASP.NET Core MVC - Partial view only renders on one page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a partial view for ViewBag.count, which is defined in the ShoppingCartController. The problem is that the ViewBag will only show when you are on the ShoppingCart View. I want the ViewBag to be seen on all views. How do I fix this? I am currently rendering the partial like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_ShoppingCart", new List<bytme.Models.ShoppingCartModel>())
```

The partial view called _ShoppingCart:

```
<span class="badge">@ViewBag.count</span>
```

Comment: Your partial does not have a `@model xxx` so passing `new List<bytme.Models.ShoppingCartModel>()` to it does not make sense. And a partial should not have `<html>` and `<body>` tags. If the controller method you called sets a value for `ViewBag.count` then that value will be displayed in your partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a seperate action method which returns  HTML markup needed to render the cart section of your page and include that in all your view using Html.Action method.

You may also decorate this action method with `ChildActionOnly` attribute so that users's cannot directly access this action method by requesting the url `/ShoppingCart/Cart`.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Cart()
{
    ViewBag.ItemCount = 2;  // replace hard coded value with your actual value
    return PartialView();
}
```

and in your partial view (`~/Views/Shared/Cart.cshtml`), you may write the HTML code which is needed for the cart segment of the page.

```
<span class="mycart">
    Total items in cart @ViewBag.ItemCount
</span>
```

Here we are using ViewBag to pass the item count numeric value from the action method to it's partial view. But you may use a view model and use the strongly typed view approach to pass data from your action method to the partial view (this is my preferred approach).

Now in other views/layout file where you want to render the cart HTML, you can call the `Html.Action` method

```
<div>
   @Html.Action("Cart","ShoppingCart")
</div>
<h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
```

When razor execute your view, it will see this Html.Action method and that will be executed and the output of that (the HTML markup generated fro the action method), will be included in the final output generated for the current view.

I am using the `PartialView` method, so that it will not try to execute the Layout code. (People make this mistake and gets an infinite calls to the Cart action method.

**For Asp.Net Core projects**

If you want to do the same thing in asp.net core projects, you may use View components to achieve the same results.

Create a view component to render the cart.

```
public class CartViewComponent : ViewComponent
{        
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string name)
    {
        var totalItemCount = 3;
        return View(totalItemCount);
    }
}
```

Create a razor view for this view component with the name `Default.cshtml` inside `~/Views/Shared/Components/Cart` directory and you can have your razor code/HTML markup inside that to render the desired HTML. In this example,  I am using a strongly typed approach where my view is stongly typed to `int` type and I am passing an int value from the the `Invoke` method when calling the `View` method.

```
@model int
<span>
    Total items : @Model
</span>
```

Now you can invoke this view component in other views/ layout file by calling the `Component.InvokeAsync` method.

```
<div>
   @await Component.InvokeAsync("Cart")
</div>
<h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
```

Comment: I tried this, but `@Html.Action` does not exist. Only `@Html.ActionLink` is an option

Comment: Are you using asp.net core ?

Comment: Yes, I added the `.csproj` to the question which has `PackageReferences` for asp.net core

Comment: I posted an update to the answer to handle the asp.net core use case.

Comment: Is it possible to use Identity in Component Views? Because I am running into an error now

Comment: You should be able to do stuff you do in your controller action methods inside your view components as well, like using dependency injection.

Comment: I added the Component View to the question with the error included, could you please look at it? In the controller it works perfectly, but for some reason in the Component View it doesn't work

Comment: What is `User` and where are you defining `User` ?

Comment: It is defined in the ControllerBase (metadata). It gets the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal for user associated with the executing action. `public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }`

Comment: Try `Request.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue`

Comment: Yes, thanks the error is gone, I will now create the razor view for it and I'll tell you if it works

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, although I didn't need to call the model in my razor view. Can't thank u enough! :)